# How can i use webpack to perform the same result that babel-cli generates

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I want to transpile a folder with webpack but don't want to apply any chunk system or something like that. I want to transpile exactly the amount of files following the same file names. Using webpack right now I it duplicates code if I use a moduleimport of a file and transpile in multiple files.

Comment: you probably don't need webpack in that case. only babel will suffice

Comment: I use webpack with multipla configurations. When it generates a bundle for client, it works as expected, but don't want to do the same for the code on server-side.